# When i send a image through mailcomposeviewcontroller.I got error MailCompositionServices quit unexpectedly in xcode 6

Tags: xcode-6.2, ios8.2

Process:               MailCompositionService [9497]
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 117.5.4 - Device: iPhone 6 - Runtime: iOS 8.2 (12D508) - DeviceType: iPhone 6

Dear Sir,
[mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"maheshjuvva@gmail.com"]];
           NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"114-x-114.png"])];

Please help me:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO834.png

This is Error Url:https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxZCk.png

Comment: if we check the url.you can find subject but we can not get body and image of the subject.

Comment: Second one is the error url.